# What is default color of solid in drawable resource for shape in Android?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-shape

What is default color of solid in drawable resource for shape??

**#1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />
</shape>
```

**#2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

If I code like #1, what is default color of solid attribute??

I have thought default color is #00000000(which is transparent color).

Is there any difference between **#1** and **#2** ?